# focus-within css not working for html label

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to build a dropdown list with checkboxes in dropdown area.

Here is the code I'm using:

```css
.search-box {
  color: black;
  width: 450px;
}

.search-box .fake-tb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 35px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.search-box .fake-tb * {
  border: 0 !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

.search-box .fake-tb input[type=search] {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100% !important;
  outline: none;
}

.search-box .fake-tb img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}

.search-box .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  cursor: default;
  background: white;
  z-index: 99999;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-box:focus-within .dropdown {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.search-box .dropdown>table {
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-box .dropdown table tr:hover {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div>line before ...</div>
<div class="search-box">
  <div class="fake-tb">
    <input name="ctl32$txtCusSearch" id="ctl32_txtCusSearch" auto-complete="off" type="search">
    <img src="search.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <table id="ctl32_lstOptions">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input id="ctl32_lstOptions_0" name="ctl32$lstOptions$0" type="checkbox" value="Value1"><label for="ctl32_lstOptions_0">Checkbox 1</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input id="ctl32_lstOptions_1" name="ctl32$lstOptions$1" type="checkbox" value="Value2"><label for="ctl32_lstOptions_1">Checkbox 2</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input id="ctl32_lstOptions_2" name="ctl32$lstOptions$2" type="checkbox" value="Value3"><label for="ctl32_lstOptions_2">Checkbox 3</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input id="ctl32_lstOptions_3" name="ctl32$lstOptions$3" type="checkbox" value="Value4"><label for="ctl32_lstOptions_3">Checkbox 4</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input id="ctl32_lstOptions_4" name="ctl32$lstOptions$4" type="checkbox" value="Value5"><label for="ctl32_lstOptions_4">Checkbox 5</label></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div>line after ...</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

There are 2 problems I'm struggling with:

1. Clicking on checkbox works fine, but clicking on its label closes the dropdown. How can I keep it open?
2. How do I make the width of dropdown equal to the textbox area, without specifying a fixed width?

I'll prefer a pure CSS solution if possible.

Comment: Instead of using `for` to connect the label, wrap the checkbox with the label.

Comment: It is generated code from `asp.net checkedlistbox`. I don't have much control over it.

Comment: I tried both ways wrapping label inside checkbox and vice-versa. No luck.

Comment: #2 is easy enough: add `.search-box { position: relative; }`  and `.dropdown { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Explain how `focus-within` has anything to do with your problem?

Comment: @zer00ne, On investigation I find that the somehow click on label causes focus to be set on `body` which ultimately causes `.search-box:focus-within .dropdown` style to deactivate since the focus is no longer inside the `.search-box`. However I don't know what the solution could be.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, thank you :)

Comment: @PradeepKumar the only way you get focus on body is to intentionally focus on window after a blur as in actually using the method `window.focus()`.

Comment: @zer00ne, yes that's a mystery. I was expecting focus on the related checkbox. But you can see it happening in the code snippet I posted and there is no javascript at all.

Comment: @PradeepKumar there might be a problem with the label + input association try removing all `for` attributes from all labels. Also, I noticed `.dropdown` is `posabs` (`position: absolute`) but it's parent is static (not `relative`, `absolute` or `sticky`. Try removing `posabs` or make parent of `.dropdown` `posrel`.

Comment: @zer00ne, yes I've tried adding `position: relative;` on `search-box`. I have also tried various things with label like removing the `for` attribute, nesting label inside checkbox and vice-versa, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

`:focus-within` activates when an element within your div is focused. However, most elements, including `label`, cannot be focused on. `input` *can* be, which is why your dropdown doesn't disappear on checking a checkbox.

To fix this simply add the `tabindex="0"` attribute to your `label` elements.